# How to use source file's path from gulp.src in gulp.dest?

Tags: gulp, gulp-sass

I want to run gulp sass task and obtain smth like this:

From:

```
/app
  /componentA
    fileA.scss
  /componentB
    fileB.scss
  /componentC
    fileC.scss
/dist
  /componentA
  /componentB
  /componentC
```

To:

```
/app
  /componentA
    fileA.scss
  /componentB
    fileB.scss
  /componentC
    fileC.scss
/dist
  /componentA
    fileA.css
  /componentB
    fileB.css
  /componentC
    fileC.css
```

Without putting this all to one folder "dist/css".

Me current code related to sass:

```
var target = {
    css: 'dist/css',
    sass: 'app/scss/*.scss'    
};

gulp.task('sass', function () {
  return gulp.src(target.sass)
   .pipe(plumber(function () {
            console.log('[sass]'.bold.magenta + ' Sass compiling error\n'.bold.red);
            this.emit('end');
        }))
    .pipe(changed(target.css))
    .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(target.css));
});
```

I have read other topics, but they do not correspond to my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is as simple as changing your globbing patterns:

```
var target = {
    css: 'dist',
    sass: 'app/**/*.scss'
};
```

You should probably read the [GulpJS documentation](http://gulpjs.org/index.html) and brush up on [node-glob](https://github.com/isaacs/node-glob).